# SELECT statement not returning MAX number

Tags: android, select, cursor

I'm having an issue with the SELECT statement in the following code (this is in my database helper class):

```
public Cursor selectMaxAreaNumber (long inspectionId) { 
String inspectionIdString = String.valueOf(inspectionId); 
String[] tableColumns = new String[] {  
        AREA_NUMBER,  
        "(SELECT max(" + AREA_NUMBER + ") FROM " + AREAS_TABLE + ") AS max"  
    };  
String whereClause = INSPECTION_LINK + " = ?"; 
String[] whereArgs = new String[] { 
        inspectionIdString           
    }; 
Cursor c = rmDb.query(AREAS_TABLE, tableColumns, whereClause, whereArgs,  
        null, null, null); 


if (c != null) { 
    c.moveToFirst(); 
} 
c.close(); 
return c;
```

}

I then call this in my activity as follows:

```
Cursor c = rmDbHelper.selectMaxAreaNumber(inspectionId); 
    startManagingCursor(c); 
    c.moveToFirst(); 
    nextAreaNumber = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("max")) + 1;
```

It is pulling the maximum number from the table, so it seems the WHERE statement is failing.  However, I can't see what the issue is.

As part of this question, can anyone confirm if I am doing the right thing by converting the ID into a String before it is used in the query and do I need to write c.moveToFirst() in both bits?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: the nested `SELECT` statement is executed before the `WHERE` clause is applied. So it's working as intended although not in the way you intended :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public Cursor selectMaxAreaNumber (long inspectionId) { 
    String[] tableColumns = new String[] {  
        "Max(" + AREA_NUMBER + ") AS max"  
    };  
    String whereClause = INSPECTION_LINK + " = ?"; 
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { 
        String.valueOf(inspectionId); 
    }; 
    return rmDb.query(AREAS_TABLE, tableColumns, whereClause, whereArgs,  
        null, null, null); 
}
```

This will return a Cursor with the largest `AREA_NUMBER` that has the appropriate `inspectionId`.

A couple notes:

- When you use a function like `Max()` you only get one row as a result, there is no need to ask for `AREA_NUMBERS` *and* `Max(AREA_NUMBERS)`
- A Cursor might be *empty*, but it won't be `null`
- Don't close a Cursor before you have used it

So you don't need this:

```
if (c != null) { 
    c.moveToFirst(); 
} 
c.close();
```

Understand that if `c` somehow was `null`, you will still receive a NullPointerException on `c.close()`

---

(Optional) You could remove the `whereArgs` and just use:

```
String whereClause = INSPECTION_LINK + " = " + inspectionId;
```

(Only because `inspectionId` is `long` data type, you need a String to perform an injection attack.)

---

Finally you should check for an empty Cursor here:

```
Cursor c = rmDbHelper.selectMaxAreaNumber(inspectionId); 
startManagingCursor(c); 
if(c.moveToFirst()) 
    nextAreaNumber = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("max")) + 1;
else //empty Cursor, return a default value
    nextAreaNumber = 0;
```

Comment: I gave a tick for both, but this solution was perfect. Thank you for the extra information.  I have removed the cursor.close() statement from the database helper class, however I have assumed that I should close a cursor once used in my other activities (cursor management is very confusing!!).  Cheers Sam.

Comment: "(cursor management is very confusing!!)" Yes it can be. Close your Cursor after you have finished reading the data with `getInt()`, `getString()`, etc. But since you are using `startManagingCursor()` this will close the Cursor for you!

Answer (score 1):

Try change

"(SELECT max(" + AREA_NUMBER + ") FROM " + AREAS_TABLE + ") AS max"

to

"SELECT max(" + AREA_NUMBER + ") AS max FROM " + AREAS_TABLE

Comment: Ahh, just realised that I can't give two ticks!  I have given it to Sam as his answer was so detailed, but thank you for the response Rainwork. Much appreciated.